# FacebookBlackBerrySDK-v0.8.25.jar works on simulator but not device

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I'm using FacebookBlackBerrySDK-v0.8.25.jar in order to be able to get user information.

My code:

```
private String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"; 
private String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.USER_DATA_PERMISSIONS;
private String APPLICATION_ID = 
private String APPLICATION_SECRET = 
ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);
FacebookUser user = fb.getCurrentUser();
```

and then I want to access various data in the FacebookUser object.

This works fine in the simulator:  if I am not signed in to the BB Facebook app I am prompted to enter my Facebook credentials and if I am signed in then I just get back a FacebookUser object.

The problem is when I move it to an actual device and am not signed in to Facebook.  I get screen where I enter my Facebook credentials but then am taken to a screen that says Page Not Found.

Its almost as though http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html doesn't exist.

Has anyone encountered this before and solved it?

Mark

Comment: Done.  

Thanks for the reminder.

Sorry for the delay.

Comment: If you solve the problem write the solution and accept your answer is solution